# Sepolia - stalled on waitForDeployment

Tags: hardhat-deploy, alchemy, sepolia

I use Hardhat and have some scripts to perform functions, such as deploy.

I've been using Goerli but have been aware that it is being shuttered, and also i've found the transaction fee to be high and often failing due to insufficient Eth.  So I moved to Sepolia.  But I have not had one successful contract deployment yet in the 3 or 4 hours I've been trying.

There doesn't seem to be any other posts on this - so I ask - is Sepolia extremely fragile or unable to cater for the new demand that has been placed upon it?

I have this deploy script (just consider this as a standin for the hardhat `Lock.sol` deploy example (few names changed etc..)):

```
async function deployJustNFT() {
  const [signer] = await getSigners();
  const signerAddress = await signer.getAddress();
  console.log(`Deply JustNFT - signer: ${signerAddress}`)

  const nft = await ethers.deployContract("MerchNFT721", [signerAddress]);
  console.log(`deployed now wait for it`);
  await nft.waitForDeployment();

  console.log(`    NFT deployed to ${await nft.getAddress()}`);
  await verify(await nft.getAddress());
}
```

When deployed it stalls at `deployed now wait for it`.

```
▶ ./hardhat_runDeployJustNFT.sh -n sepolia
Network: sepolia
Address:
Use sepolia network
Deply JustNFT - signer: 0x8783746a70ABA0587f9C872Bf52f952E50208730
deployed now wait for it
```

If I change to use `goerli` it works fine.

The `hardhat.config.ts` is the same for both but for the URL. And I am using the same script.  So the problem is Sepolia.  Is this a known issue and is it being addressed?  Both URLs are Alchemy RPCs (eg `https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/xyz...` and sepolia equivalent from Alchemy).

```
const accounts=[process.env.ACCOUNT_1_PK, process.env.ACCOUNT_2_PK, process.env.ACCOUNT_3_PK];

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  defaultNetwork: 'localhost',
  solidity: "0.8.23",
  paths: {
    // Frontend code require access to the artifacts
    artifacts: "./src/artifacts"
  },
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: process.env.GOERLI_URL,
      // @ts-ignore
      accounts,
    },
    sepolia: {
      url: process.env.SEPOLIA_URL,
      // @ts-ignore
      accounts,
    },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
  },
};
```

Prior to this stalling behaviour, the deploy would seem to complete but I could not view the contract address in https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address - there would be no transactions against it.

Again, no problems in Goerli and I could view the verified contract immediately.

Sepolia issues?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've got it.  The problem was the Alchemy RPC and once I switched to using a public one, specifically https://sepolia.gateway.tenderly.co from https://chainlist.org/chain/11155111 it worked a treat.  I will try the Alchemy one tomorrow and if it still fails then I will work out how to ping them about it.

Comment: Alchemy came good by next day